# my search View is not working, not filtering the result (in recycler View)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, searchview

My mainAcivity2 code :

```
  //for searchView
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if(clientList.contains(query)){
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"No Match Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

its my mainActiviy2 code where I want to implement the search View. I have 2 recycler views here. One is horizontal recycler View and the other is vertical recycler View. I want to use search View in vertical recycler View.

My adapter code:

```
public class ClientAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClientAdapter.ClientViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private Context context;
    private List<Clientt> clienttList;
    List<Clientt> clienttListAll;

    public ClientAdapter(Context context, List<Clientt> clienttList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.clienttList = clienttList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ClientViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_item_client, parent, false);
        return new ClientAdapter.ClientViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ClientViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textViewClientName.setText(clienttList.get(position).getClientName());
        holder.textViewClientNumber.setText(clienttList.get(position).getPhoneNumber());
        String s = clienttList.get(position).getClientName();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return clienttList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }
    Filter filter=new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                clienttListAll = clienttList;
            } else {
                List<Clientt> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Clientt row : clienttList) {

                    // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                    // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                    if (row.getClientName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getPhoneNumber().contains(charSequence)) {
                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }
                }

                clienttListAll = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = clienttListAll;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

            clienttListAll = (ArrayList<Clientt>) filterResults.values;

            // refresh the list with filtered data
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };


    public class ClientViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {



            private TextView textViewClientName;
            private TextView textViewClientNumber;
            LinearLayout ly;


            public ClientViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                textViewClientName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_client_name);
                textViewClientNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_client_number);
                ly = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listtt_Client);


            }
        }
    }
```

When I run my application , it always a toast is shown whenever I search anything "No Match Found".
its the else part in my code...seems like "if" condition is not working.

**Thankyou for your help in advance.**

Comment: Hi You try to check if the list contain a String object but your list contains Client object not a String for that your if statement return always false

Comment: If you really need the if statement you need to change the Client class by overriding the equals method and in the if statement you should use something like `if (listClient.contains (new Client (" client name query"))`

Comment: it is showing error when i am doing this changes

Comment: Why you don't set the items to `clientListAll` in the constructor? Only the filtered list should be manipulated, not the full list which one needs to populate the filtered list.

Answer (score 0):

return true in your OnQueryTextListener

```
@Override
  public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
  {
      adapter.filter(query);
      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
  {
      adapter.filter(query);
      return true;
  }
```

adapter

```
public class ClientAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClientAdapter.ClientViewHolder>
{
    private Context context;
    private List<Clientt> clienttList;
    List<Clientt> clienttListAll;

    public ClientAdapter(Context context, List<Clientt> clienttList)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.clienttList = clienttList;
        clienttListAll.addAll(clienttList);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ClientViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_item_client, parent, false);
        return new ClientAdapter.ClientViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ClientViewHolder holder, int position)
    {

        holder.textViewClientName.setText(clienttList.get(position).getClientName());
        holder.textViewClientNumber.setText(clienttList.get(position).getPhoneNumber());
        String s = clienttList.get(position).getClientName();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return clienttList.size();
    }

    public void filter(String charText)
    {
        clienttList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0)
        {
            clienttList.addAll(clienttListAll);
        }
        else
        {
            for (Clientt row : clienttListAll)
            {
                // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                if (row.getClientName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getPhoneNumber().contains(charSequence))
                {
                    clienttList.add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public class ClientViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView textViewClientName;
        private TextView textViewClientNumber;
        LinearLayout ly;


        public ClientViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            textViewClientName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_client_name);
            textViewClientNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_client_number);
            ly = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listtt_Client);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried removing filterable from adapter?

Comment: now showing unresolved reference on charSequence, charString in adapter class and showing error on query, and getFilter in mainActivity

Comment: remove getFilter() from MainActivity and call adapter.filter(query) this

Comment: error is on charSequence and charString...showing unresolved reference

Comment: just replace the updated adapter code and check again

Comment: here variable name in filter method is String charText..rename it to charSeqence or charString

Comment: Share your updated adapter..what is the error

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your ClientAdapter:

```
 public ClientAdapter(Context context, List<Clientt> clienttList)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.clienttList = clienttList;
    clienttListAll=new Arraylist<>(clienttList);
}
```

Add this also:

```
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
         clientList.clear();
            clienttListAll.addAll((List) filterResults.values);

        // refresh the list with filtered data
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I will suggest you to try this full code IF nothing works:

My adapter code:

```
 public class ClientAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClientAdapter.ClientViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private Context context;
private List<Clientt> clienttList;
List<Clientt> clienttListAll;

public ClientAdapter(Context context, List<Clientt> clienttList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.clienttList = clienttList;
    clientListAll=new Arraylist<>(clientList);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ClientViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_item_client, parent, false);
    return new ClientAdapter.ClientViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ClientViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.textViewClientName.setText(clienttList.get(position).getClientName());
    holder.textViewClientNumber.setText(clienttList.get(position).getPhoneNumber());
    String s = clienttList.get(position).getClientName();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return clienttList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return filter;
}
Filter filter=new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
       List<Clientt> filteredList= new Arraylist<>();
        String charString = charSequence.toString();
        if (charString.isEmpty()) {
            filteredList.addAll(clienttListAll);
        } else {
            String filtered=charString.toLowerCase().trim();
            for (Clientt row : clienttList) {

                // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                if (row.getClientName().toLowerCase().contains(filtered) || row.getPhoneNumber().contains(charSequence)) {
                    filteredList.add(row);
                }
            }

   
        }

        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        filterResults.values = filteredList;
        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        clienList.clear();

        clienttList.addAll((List)filterResults.values);

        // refresh the list with filtered data
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Comment: Do this also

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
clientList.clear();
            clienttListAll.addAll((List) filterResults.values);

            // refresh the list with filtered data
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }